# C++ and C non-member multiple structs initialization

Tags: c++

How to initialize two or more structures with the same data? This has to be done at compile time to be as default data for const structures that are non-member global variables.

EDIT:
And what about C?

Comment: Are the structures the same layout-wise?

Comment: `a = b = c = d = { ... }`?

Comment: Yes, structures are of the same type.

Comment: It does not work that way, because declaration in that case is separate from definition.

Answer (score 3):

Works for me:

```
// header
struct Foo {
        int a;
        int b;                            
};
extern Foo const x;
extern Foo const y;

// cpp file
Foo const x{2, 3};
Foo const y = x;
```

Edit: reinterpreted the question a little.

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

```
#define DATA { bla,bla,bla,bla }

var a = DATA;
var b = DATA;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the copy constructor to initialize the structs. (This requires the use of a helper function to ensure correct order of initialization.) If the structures are POD, this should be as efficient as regular compile-time initialization:

```
struct A {
  int a;
  double c;
};

A initial_data() {
  return { 1, 2.0 };
}

A a = initial_data();
A b = initial_data();
```